# Loop I/PhoneWindow: generateLayout isLightNavi false, Visibility: 0 I/DecorView: It non-support bigbang

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I'm having a weird loop on debug in Android Studio, and my app doesn't open. I'm using API 28 (Android Pie)
Any idea about what is the problem?

`I/DecorView: It non-support bigbang
I/PhoneWindow: generateLayout isLightNavi false, Visibility: 0
I/DecorView: It non-support bigbang
I/PhoneWindow: generateLayout isLightNavi false, Visibility: 0
I/DecorView: It non-support bigbang
I/PhoneWindow: generateLayout isLightNavi false, Visibility: 0`
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These log statements are a red herring. Are you using a Nokia by chance? I noticed the bigbang log statement on my device as well. My guess is that Nokia added this log statement as part of some modifications they made to the system image. This is unfortunately common in Android development. I often notice strange log statements in my app's logcat, which may look like errors, but aren't related to my app's code at all.

If your logcat doesn't show an additional error besides what you shared, try turning off the "Show only selected application" filter. Sometimes when an app fails to start, the system will log an error instead of your app's process.

Comment: Yeah, I use a Nokia 8. Thanks for these informations about Nokia phones.

Comment: My suspicion was correct! Please consider accepting this answer.